# How to align text vertically and horizontally in table cells of the same column?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabularx, ragged2e

I want to **top align** and **right justify** the text in all tabularx cells of a certain column.
So far, I tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R{2cm}|X|} \hline
A text on multiple lines & \shortstack{Line1 \\ Line2 \\ Line3 \\Line4 \\ Line5} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

`\RaggedLeft` command seems to override the top alignment of `p{'size'}` column type in array package. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That `\hspace` isn't very well there. In addition, I suggest to use the `multirow` - package

Comment: Thank you! I removed the `\hspace{0pt}`, it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trial solution, since I don't know the first column should be aligned really:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=3cm]{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R{2cm}|X|} 
  \hline
  \multirow{5}{*}{\makecell[rt]{A text on\\ multiple lines}} & Line1 \tabularnewline
  & Line2  \tabularnewline 
  & Line3 \tabularnewline 
  & Line4 \tabularnewline 
  & Line5 \tabularnewline 
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|R{2cm}|X|} 
  \hline
  \multirowcell{1}[0pt][tR{2cm}]{A text on  multiple lines} & Line1 \tabularnewline
                                                            & Line2  \tabularnewline 
                                                            & Line3 \tabularnewline 
                                                            & Line4 \tabularnewline 
                                                            & Line5 \tabularnewline 
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think about the alignment of the first column